# $\sum r^n |\sin(nx)|$ convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Verify if the series
>
> $$\sum r^n |\sin(nx)|,\qquad r>0$$
>
> Converges or diverges

I've tried some comparisons with known series and the convergence tests, but didn't work. I think we should use the root test, but I don't know the limit of $|\sin(nx)|^{1/n}$

Comment: If $|r|<1$ observe that $r^n|\sin(nx)|<|r|^n$ and see that it converges.

Comment: Ok, this I noted, but I dont know how to treat the other cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For $|r|<1$ we have

$$|r^n|\cdot|\sin(nx)|\le |r^n|$$
and since $\sum|r^n|$ is a convergent geometric series then the given series is convergent for all $x$ by comparison.

- Otherwise, and if $x\ne0$ we have $r^n|\sin(nx)|\not\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$ hence the series is divergent.